# Laravel-generated email not formatting HTML correctly

Tags: html, laravel, email, laravel-5, html-email

I am struggling with email formatting issue, with Laravel.
I get the email content (HTML) from the database, which doesn't really matter, but then quotes get added around, the format is wrong and my email looks like this:

[image: t formatting my email corres]

Here is my code, thanks a lot for your help!

I tried with
'content' => htmlspecialchars($content)
and
'content' => htmlentities($content)
but none work, and for the blade file:

```
<div>
    {{!!$content!!}}
</div>
```

gives me an error. I also tried

```
<div>
    {{{$content}}}
</div>
```

(also an error of unexpected character) and

```
<div>
    {{$content}}
</div>
```

(here was the original one)

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class InsuranceEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $attacheddoc;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($attacheddoc)
    {
        $this->attacheddoc=$attacheddoc;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.rubr
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $name = Auth::user()->nom . " " .  Auth::user()->prenom;

        $sqlContent="SELECT texte from blabla";

        $content = DB::connection('blabla')->select( DB::connection('blabla')->raw($sqlContent))[0]->texte;
        $content = str_replace('#memberName#', $name, $content);
        $content = str_replace('"', '', $content); //I tried this, without any hope ;)

        return $this->from('contact@blabla.net')
                ->markdown('emails.blabla')->with([
                    'title' => "Email onject",
                    'memberName' => $name,
                    'content' => $content,
                ])
                ->attach($this->attacheddoc, array(
                    'as' => 'attacheddoc.pdf', 
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use {!! $content !!} on your view file

Comment: you have used `{{!!$content!!}}` try  `{!! $content !!}`

Comment: Thanks, I tried both :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a few things to try and fix my email displaying incorrectly. In the end clearing my view cache solved my problem, which I hadn't seen anyone else suggest. This most likely wasn't your issue here but I will include it in my answer to hopefully help anyone else with my issue.

Publish the Laravel email views

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Make sure there are no indents in your html views

```
resources/views/vendor/mail/html
```

Make sure to escape any html inserted via variable

```
{!! $content !!}
```

Clear cached views

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **emails.blabla** view us elike this it will escape **HTML** element

`{{{ $content }}}`

or try

`{!! $content !!}`

Comment: same for both... very strange, I don't get this!

Comment: I tried:
<div>{{!! $content !!}}</div> ,  <div>{!! $content !!}</div>
The file is extremely simple as you can see :D

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Documentation:

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Reference:

[Laravel -> Blade Templates -> Displaying Unescaped Data](http://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: For some reason I also get 'undexpected character" error if I write <div>{{!! $content !!}}</div>. And if I write <div>{!! $content !!}</div>, I only get "{!! $content !!}" as an email (without the content)